# how to fix my position sticky with navigation bar problem

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I'm building a responsive website with a header above the navigation bar and my goal is then of course to have the navigation bar stick to the top when scrolling down.

I'm new to *HTML* and *CSS*, so I'm not really sure if the order in what should be in the top of the *CSS* class code for the navbar should be. But just in case I've put `position:sticky;` at the top and then the `top:0;` value second to that. I've also tried to put it directly in the head. But to no avail. I'll include the code for you to see.

```css
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  height: 74px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #A6A6A6;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">
      <button class="btn text1">Text 1</button>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <button class="btn text2">Text 2</button>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <button class="btn text3">Text 3</button>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <button class="btn text4">Text 4</button>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <button class="btn text5">Text 5</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add position:sticky to the parent.
(Also make sure you always check for [browser compatibilty](https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky))

```
nav {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;    
  background-color: black;
  height: 74px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;   
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#A6A6A6;   
 }
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9fvwp7x1/5/

Answer (score 0):

Make the `navbar` class fixed. It will stick it there.
Either way it wont stick. Example;

```css
.navbar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```